# How to disable Edge showing on top of start menu when searching for Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Whenever I try to type Internet Explorer in the start menu, the new Edge browser is at the top and automatically selected. For some enterprise tools we still need IE. (I'm aware of the security issues)

[image: Edge at top of start menu]

**How can I disable Edge showing up at the top when searching for Internet Explorer, without uninstalling edge?**

This started after update 2004 of Windows 10.
Current windows version = 19041.388

Maybe anybody knows the registery key to disable this behavior or a different way.

There once was a `x` next to Microsoft Edge, I clicked it, but the behavior didn't change.

Comment: There's no way to remove Edge. You could perhaps try to reindex the Start Menu by *Indexing Options > Advanced > Rebuild*.

Comment: @harrymc - Author is looking to disable the suggestion which absolutely can be disable.  It also is possible to uninstall Chromium Edge which will make legacy Edge available

Comment: @Ramhound: If this is a notification and not a search result, then it can be undone in *Settings > Personalization > Start* and turn to Off the option "Show suggestions occasionally in Start". But I'm not sure about it.